# tomcat java : class path resource [my-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, war, tomcat8

I can not deploy my .war file on tomcat8.

Here is the logs in the localhost file log:

```
06-Dec-2017 11:18:22.001 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
06-Dec-2017 11:18:22.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
06-Dec-2017 11:18:22.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
06-Dec-2017 11:18:34.230 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@5a8b94fb]
06-Dec-2017 11:18:34.350 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
06-Dec-2017 11:18:36.864 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:security-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [ws-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:165)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1129)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1871)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [security-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:223)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here is the content of ws-context.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.engie.aurora" />

<import resource="classpath:core-context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:security-context.xml" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:tech.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="log4jInitialization"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:log4j.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven
    ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />

    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Here is the content of /opt/tomcat/conf/context.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Environment override="false" value="${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/myapp/" 
type="java.lang.String" name="myappConfigDirectory" />

</Context>
```

`CATALINA_BASE` is an environment variable with this value : `/opt/tomcat`

The security-context.xml file is located here : `/opt/tomcat/conf/myapp/security-context.xml`

The app is located here : `/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war`

Could you please help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: security-context.xml should be under WEB-INF/securityContext.xml

Comment: Hello, i have the same error when i put security-context.xml  in WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by coping the security-conext.yml file in the same location of ws-content.xml file.

Many thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Cao